# Dynamically setting CSS Top and Left on Aurelia component

Tags: css, aurelia

Using Aurelia, I created a very simple component with HTML:

`<template>
       <h1 
       draggable="true"
       css="width: ${width}px; 
       height: ${height}px; 
       color:${color};
       left: ${left}">
           ${message}
       </h1>
    </template>`

And TypeScript:

`export class Navigation { 
      message: string = 'Component Text';
      width = '400'
      height = '250'
      color = 'red'
      left = '100'
    }`

All the CSS attributes works as expected, except the **left: 100px**

The objective is to use the **top** and **left** to dynamically set the position of the component. This is also the reason for the **draggable="true"** attribute.

I can see in the rendered HTML the **left: 100px** is present but has no effect.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Position** CSS property should be set to 'relative' or 'absolute' in order to get it working: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp